# Android application checklist prior to distribution 

Tags: android, distribution

Hi I have just finished debugging my first application and want to publish it.  I would like to know if you have a checklist that you use prior to distribution.

For instance I have lots of Log.d() commands, must I remove them?  I have rotated my screens as much as possible to cause stop/restart failures.  These are the types of test I  am looking for.

Being my first app I am sure there are items of concern I am missing and will greatly appreciate your help and insight.

If it makes a difference I am using Motodev in eclipse.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unitary test and you should do all those test each time you sent updates of your app.

Check here : http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html

For publishing app you have to pay a 30$ fee and subscribe to google system

For log.d(), I think the debuggable="true" into the manifest will do the job but i'm not sure at all !

Comment: That developer link was great, just to sort of info I was looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have shared the general guidelines for Android app delivery [Click Here](https://androiddhamu.blogspot.in/2017/10/android-app-delivery-checklist.html)

These guidelines will help you to upload an Android app without any last minute chaos.